# Linq2Sql relationships and WCF serialization problem

Tags: linq, wcf, asp.net-ajax

here is my scenario 
i got

Table1

- id
- name

Table2

- id
- family
- fid

with one to many relationship set between Table1. id and Table2.fid

now here is my WCF service Code

```
 [OperationContract]

public List<Table1> GetCustomers(string numberToFetch)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        return context.Table1s.Take(int.Parse(numberToFetch)).ToList( );
    }
}
```

and my ASPX page Code

```
<body xmlns:sys="javascript:Sys"   
    xmlns:dataview="javascript:Sys.UI.DataView">  
  <div id="CustomerView"   
      class="sys-template"  
      sys:attach="dataview"  
      dataview:autofetch="true"  
      dataview:dataprovider="Service2.svc"  
      dataview:fetchParameters="{{ {numberToFetch: 2} }}"  
      dataview:fetchoperation="GetCustomers">  
      <ul>  
          <li>{{family}}</li>  
      </ul>  
  </div>
```

though i set serialization mode to Unidirectional in Linq2Sql designer i am not able to get the family value and all what i get is this in firebug

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Table1:#","id":1,"name":"asd"},{"__type":"Table1:#","id":2,"name":"wewe"}]}
```

any help would be totally appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well, the point is: your method `GetCustomers` only ever selects from `Table1` - I don't see any reference at all to `Table2`, where your `Family` column is located......

You need to check into Linq-to-SQL JOIN's and how to fetch data from a joined table into your result set.

Something along the lines of:

```
[DataContract]
class JoinedResult
{   
   [DataMember]
   public int Table1ID { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Table1Name { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Table2Family { get; set; }
}  

[OperationContract]
public List<JoinedResult> GetCustomers(int numberToFetch)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var q = from t1 in context.Table1
                join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.id = t2.fid
                select new JoinedResult
                           { Table1ID = t1.ID,
                             Table1Name = t1.Name,
                             Table2Family = t2.Family };

        return q.Take(numberToFetch).ToList();
    }
}
```

and btw: you should really make `numberToFetch` an INT parameter! Let the caller make the conversion......

UPDATE: if you don't want to explicitly include the second table to be queried, you could instead add a `DataLoadOption` to your context:

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Table1>(t => t.Table2);

context.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

In that case, you tell LINQ to always include all elements from `Table2` when it loads anything from `Table1` - that should work, too.

Comment: thanks alot for the answer, i may be wrong, but with Linq2sql mapping table2 is a property of table1 thus there is no need to join and i can access it like Table1.Table2, correct me if i am wrong please.

Comment: @devmania: yes, you could - but that doesn't mean it gets serialized back to the client. When you select *only* from Table1, then there's no inclination for Linq-to-SQL to include all Table2 properties as well. If you want to, you need to ask for it. But you're right - you could write: `Table2Family = t1.Table2.Family` as the last line in the select statement in LINQ

Comment: bro thanks alot for your detailed answer, but the the thing is that i am creating a pluggable system so i want t a way to just pick up the new child tables without reediting my WCF code, so dataoption will not work because i have to reedit it every-time i add  new plugin, this is really driving me crazy